# Are woodworking questions in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've had a few questions that deal more with woodworking than with home improvement per se:

- [best materials for non toxic wooden blocks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2501/22)
- [Making your own height adjustable desk](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1928/22)
- [How to paint Pine furniture](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1992/22)
- [Dresser/Chest with convex front](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1356/22)
- [others...](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood)

Should we include these types of questions in our scope?

Comment: Until there's somewhere better to ask, I've added "Carpentry and woodworking." to the on-topic section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think they all should be in scope.  Yes we are Home Improvement.  But we are also DIY which implies handyman like things that you are doing yourself.  Making toys, blocks, furniture are handyman like things.

Being that we are having a hard time getting enough questions, we may want to broaden the scope a little more.

Comment: Essentially, changing it from "DIY home improvement" to "DIY __and__ home improvement"?

Comment: Maybe more like handyman stack exchange that home improvement.  The tag line could mention diy and home improvement

Comment: I'm for furniture questions, but don't think toy making questions should be on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

My take: if it's for a permanent or semi-permanent part of the house, it should be in scope.  Something that would or could be (for example, a bookshelf that fits in the nook under the stairs, or a daybed sized for the curve in a bay window) included when you sell the house.

By that guideline, "wooden blocks" and "convex-fronted chest" are out of scope.  If you look at the "pine furniture" question, it's actually about how to prepare the wood surface for painting, so it would be useful in other cases.  "Height adjustable desk" is narrowly in the on-topic side, mostly because the first thing I thought of when I saw the question was a cantilevered support structure bolted into the house's framing.

Comment: I would say making furniture could be close to being on-topic, but wooden blocks are defiantly not.

Comment: The furniture making issue interests me - my wife has a long list of things for me to build. :) Does anyone else have an opinion on furniture in particular?

Comment: Just to clarify, I think furniture making is at least close to being off-topic, if not entirely. It's just that **my** opinion on the matter is a bit cloudy, since I **wish** it was on-topic.

Comment: I think furniture is an important part of a home, so why not allow furniture building questions?