# Should carpentry be made on-topic in our FAQ?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are woodworking questions in scope?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/are-woodworking-questions-in-scope)

I've seen a lot of questions that are less based on home improvement that you would ask a building contractor, and more about carpentry (building a desk, supporting a fish tank, etc). Should these be made explicitly on topic in our FAQ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be open to explicitly allowing carpentry, with the proviso that we state that we would migrate those questions when a more appropriate SE is out of Beta.